# arranging the variables around when using inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra

If I want to show that $a$*$x$*$a^{-1}$ = $y$, is it acceptable to show that $x$*$a$*$a^{-1}$ = $y$ which then simplifies to $x$*$1$ so $x$=$y$?

If not, how could I reorder them using what property?

Comment: In what context did you see this? What you seem to want to do is use commutativity, but with no further context, there is no way for us to know if you can assume that things commute.

Answer (score 2):

If you have

$$a\cdot x\cdot a^{-1}=y$$

then it is perfectly valid to do

$$x\cdot a \cdot a^{-1}=y$$

Switching $x$ and $a$ is valid because multiplication is commutative, which means that $a\cdot b=b\cdot a$.
Note that if you're using some object where multiplication is not commutative, then there isn't really anything more we can do, without knowing more about the object.
$$x\cdot a^1 \cdot a^{-1}=y$$
$$x\cdot a^{1+(-1)}=y$$
$$x\cdot a^{0}=y$$
$$x\cdot1=y$$
$$x=y$$

You could argue that if $a=0$ then the above is undefined since $0^{-1}=\frac10$ is division by zero so the actual result would be

$$x=y,\quad a\ne0$$

Comment: This seems to focus on a different part of the argument from the one being asked about. The term commutative is quite important here.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I've added a note about commutativity

Comment: But you did not add any explanation for why the OP can assume that things commute (though I realize that the original tag was commutative-algebra rather than abstract algebra, one usually mainly encounters expressions like the one here in connection with groups where commutativity is not given).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft We haven't ben told anything about multiplication not being commutative, so I assumed it was. However I've added a note about it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, $a*b = b*a$ is true only if $a$ and $b$ are *commutative* under the operation $*$. Commutativity is a special property that does not always hold. For instance, if $*$ is defined as real-valued multiplication, then it is true that $a*b=b*a$ because $ab = ba$ in the reals. However, if $a,b$ are $n\times n$ matrices, and $*$ is defined as matrix multiplication, $a*b=b*a$ is rarely true!

In fact, the example you present is encountered quite frequently. Consider a diagonalizable matrix $A$. We can perform an eigendecomposition of the form
$$A = Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$$
and extract from $A$ a diagonal matrix $\Lambda$. However, $\Lambda \neq A$ unless $A$ is already diagonal.

Comment: Just a note: Operations can be commutative. Elements can commute (with each other).